# model.fit() progress bar not displaying

Tags: machine-learning, keras, progress-bar

On Keras `model.fit()` I'm using `verbose=1`, which would supposedly show the progress bar along with other data:

```
costumized_xception.fit(train_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    epochs=2,
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[es_callback, modelckpt_callback, tensorboard_callback],
                    class_weight={0:550, 1:1})
```

However, my PyCharm event log only shows this:

```
16376/Unknown - 5682s 347ms/step - loss: 0.7127
```

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: Please specify what class and in what package your model is, and also link the similar question (so we may compare what _doesn't_ work).